# How to output message after form submit on the same page?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

When a user sumbit a form I need to output message for him on the same page.

When I submit a form the page refreshes, handler fires (php function), some POST data inserts into database, I set `$this['success'] = 1` and then check with Twig:

```
{% if success %}
  here is many tags with information and a message
{% else %}
   here is a form
{% endif %}
```

But if I press F5 the form is resubmitting, the insert query executes again.

Do this request with AJAX isn't a real option.

Comment: Are you asking how you could submit the form without reloading the page?

Comment: No, how could I submit a form and output a message (block with many tags) on the same page. Not with AJAX.

Comment: Oh, seems like I found out. After form submit page reloads, a PHP function executes, at its end I set cookie and redirect to this page (post request is gone now). In `onStart` function I check if that cookie is set and set `$this['success']` to output needed block with message (code is above) and unset cookie.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure a cookie is the way to go, especially because you need to unset the cookie afterward etc, Can't you just redirect with a parameter in the url. so after submit you redirect to `http://yourwebsite.nl/submitpage?message=succes`

Comment: I use `form_open` function with request parameter.
`{{ form_open({ request: 'onBook', url: 'booking?success=1' }) }}`

When I want to get post('success') an error occurs (offset 0). I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to answer this question (use Cache, database, cookies, session). This is really easy using [Session Flashing](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/session#flash-data) or in this instance I am going to show you how to do it with [Returning a redirect with flash data.](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/response-view#redirect-flash-data)

1. Spin up a CMS Page
2. Place HTML Form code: *Note the `{{ something }}` is important to show our response after submitting the form. This request does not use AJAX.

   ```
   {{ something }}
   {{ form_open({ request: 'onSubmit', class: 'row', autocomplete: 'off' }) }}
   {{ form_input('text', 'something', '', { class: 'input padding' }) }}
   {{ form_submit('Submit', { class: 'button padding' } ) }}
   {{ form_close() }}
   ```
3. PHP code:

   ```
   function onStart() {
   $something = Session::get('something');
   $this['something'] = $something; 
   }

   function onSubmit() {
   $something = Input::get('something');
   return Redirect::refresh()->with('something', $something);
   }
   ```
4. Test and enjoy one way to create a message after submitting a form.

[image: Photo of a form for testing]
[image: Photo of the output message]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did I understand right that `with` function sets a session and after the first retrieve the session disappears?

Comment: Well a session is created when a user browses the website. The `with` function flashes data into the session for one response.

"Since HTTP driven applications are stateless, sessions provide a way to store information about the user across requests." [-OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/session)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using laravel then you can easily implement to handle this functionality

In View file you need to write this code, which will display message on the same page where you are displaying form.

**file.blade.php** file

```
   @if(Session::has('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        {{ Session::get('success') }}
                    </div>
      @endif
```

FormController.php

```
    public function addUser(Request $request){
     User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'gender' => $request->gender,
                'contact' => $request->contact,
                    .....]);
      //below code help to display the message that you want on same page whereuser entered data
      return back()->with('success', 'Thanks you for adding!!');
}
```

**return back()->with('success', 'Thanks you for adding!!');**
use this code for laravel project to display message on same page